# Php Laravel, when running php artisan serve, I get an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm working on a project in php/laravel.  I've had no issues til, now.  When I run the "php artisan serve" command I get the following error message:

In RouteCollection.php line 236:
  syntax error, unexpected 'OPTIONS' (T_STRING)

I did not change anything here, I did not change the route file, either.  I have tried switching branches and I get the same error message.  I have tried running "Composer update" command and I get the following error message:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file                es
Generating optimized autoload filcripts::postAutoloadDumpes                               -ansi

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerSver --ansi handling the post-autoload-dumpcripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover --ansi
>   Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1load-dump event returned with error code 1

In RouteCollection.php line 236:

syntax error, unexpected 'OPTIONS' (T_STRING)

I'm using php 7.1.3 and laravel 5.8.

Any ideas?  Quitting php/laravel is not an option either.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using, and which version of Laravel?

Comment: that line contains `if ($request->method() === 'OPTIONS') {`, do you have that anywhere in your views, route(), or web ?

Comment: have you tried to modify anything in vendor/laravel directory ?

Comment: "php": "^7.1.3", "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",

Comment: Compare your version with https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/5.8/RouteCollection.php , and make sure there's no weird line endings to throw it off.

Comment: @EmadHa I have not file changes in the vendor folder.  I changed branches and I got the same error.

Comment: branches don't undo the changes in vendor because it's in .gitignore, try to backup your vendors folder, then delete it, then `composer install`, this will reinstall all the vendors folder, but make sure you have it backed up the way you want in case there was actually some change.

Answer (score 0):

> Compare your version with
>   github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/5.8/RouteCollection.php , and make
>   sure there's no weird line endings to throw it off. – aynber 2 mins
>   ago

So I followed this suggestion and replace the entire RouteCollection.php file with the contents form github.